# pytest assert if a column is ascending or descending within another already sorted group

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, pytest

I am running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfTestExample = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

dfTestExample = dfTestExample.sort_values(["A", "B"], ascending = [True, False])

dfTestExample.head(10)
```

which produces

```
    A   B   C   D
303 0   84  13  96
728 0   43  48  32
558 0   35  49  49
286 0   34  17  4
652 0   29  53  4
292 0   18  62  29
139 0   17  63  99
718 1   91  6   48
611 1   83  19  75
208 1   80  35  73
```

```
dfTestExample.A.is_monotonic
True
dfTestExample.B.is_monotonic
False
```

How do I check if the column B is also montonic for all values of A?

Comment: Clarification: values of column B are also monotonic (descending for any given value of A). B is 84, 43, 35, 34.. when A is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to split the dataframe into separate groups for each value of `A`:

```py
monotonic = True
for group in df.groupby(['A']):
    b = group[1].B
    if not b.is_monotonic and not b.is_monotonic_decreasing:
        monotonic = False
print(monotonic)
```

`groupby` gives you a `DataFrameGroupBy` object. If you iterate over that object, you get tuples of index and `DataFrame` objects, and you can handle these separately. In your case the grouped `DataFrame` objects will look like:

```
    A   B   C   D
303 0   84  13  96
728 0   43  48  32
558 0   35  49  49
286 0   34  17  4
652 0   29  53  4
292 0   18  62  29
139 0   17  63  99
```

and:

```
    A   B   C   D
718 1   91  6   48
611 1   83  19  75
208 1   80  35  73
```

Note that if you want to know if a dataset is monotonically increasing *or* decreasing, you have to check both, as shown in the example.